# Biblatex authoryear dashed for entries with no year

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using biblatex authoryear and have multiple entries of the same author that do not have a year.
When I cite them there are letters shown to distinguish them:
[image: mwe]

But in the bibliography those letters are not shown and you can only distinguish them by the title.
Is it possible to show the letters in the bibliography, too?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@BOOK{bar1,
  title = {Text One},
  year = {},
  author = {Firstname Lastname},
}
@BOOK{bar2,
  title = {Text Two},
  year = {},
  author = {Firstname Lastname},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-icomp, dashed=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{bar1} and \cite{bar2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: @karlkoeller I'm not sure that is really the problem. The problem seems to lie with `biblatex` not printing any date information (if it is not available) in the bibliography. (Also these books don't have a `urldate`)

Comment: @karlkoeller Mhhh weird, it does not work here. Even with `\DeclareLabeldate{\field{date}\field{eventdate} \field{origdate}\literal{nodate}}` I do not get the "n.d." in the bibliography.

Comment: @karlkoeller Trying the proposed duplicate answer does not work for me.

Comment: @moewe I don't know what I did before and it worked, but now it doesn't work for me, either. Retracting closing vote. If the question will be closed, I'll vote for reopening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `biblatex` does not print anything in the bibliography if the `date` is not set

```
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
         {\printdateextralabel}%
         {\printfield{labelyear}%
          \printfield{extrayear}}}}}%
```

You can force `biblatex` to always print the year

```
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
      {\printdateextralabel}%
      {\printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}%
```

Or to only print the letter if no year is available

```
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
    {\printfield{extrayear}}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
         {\printdateextralabel}%
         {\printfield{labelyear}%
          \printfield{extrayear}}}}}%
```

This applies to the standard `mergedate=true`/`mergdetae=compact` setting, if you have any other `mergdate` option in place, you might have to modify the redefinitions above.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{bar1,
  title = {Text One},
  year = {},
  author = {Firstname Lastname},
}
@BOOK{bar2,
  title = {Text Two},
  year = {},
  author = {Firstname Lastname},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, dashed=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
      {\printdateextralabel}%
      {\printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}%

\begin{document}

\cite{bar1} and \cite{bar2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]